# Matlab and string latex format

Tags: matlab, latex

In Matlab, I need to format a latex string containing a numeric variable.
The string is like: foo1 , where 1 is contained in variable X and must be subscript.

This line works if I write directly the value of variable

```
str = texlabel('foo_{1}')
```

I'm wondering how to insert the X instead of the value.
In fact this line

```
str = texlabel('foo_{X}')'
```

produce, of course, fooX
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest method would be to include a call to [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
X = 1;
str = texlabel(sprintf('foo_{%u}', X));
```

Which returns:

```
str =

{foo}_{{2}}
```

Which we can plot real quick with `text(0.1, 0.1, str)`:

[image: yay]

Comment: I just found out there's an explicit LaTeX interpreter: check the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html) under "Interpreter"